# canvas animation duration in time

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html5-canvas

When in HTML canvas we want that the fps will be dynamic and don't let the user device crash we are using `requestAnimationFrame()` but who I keep the fps of the canvas animation dynamic and measure the duration of the animations in seconds that the animation at 30fps will finish at the same time as the 60fps has finished?

Comment: Use [`getMilliseconds`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMilliseconds) to measure the time between frames and factor it in your animations accordingly. Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715867/accurate-timing-with-requestanimationframe

Comment: who can I do this? I know that any frame you adding or removing the speed of the animation from one of the sizes of the canvas element that I draw

Comment: The `requestAnimationFrame` callback's first argument is a high precision timestamp (milliseconds) - use that to calculate the time passed between calls and time your animation accordingly.

Comment: tnx for helping but can you give me an example code that I will understand you more because I am didn't really understand who to measure the time between frames

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to calculate the amount of milliseconds in between frames, divide it by 1000, then multiply the result with a speed stated in pixels per second.

Here's example code that uses the timing parameter passed to `requestAnimationFrame`:

```js
var $square;
var x = 0;
var speed = 100; // pixels per second

var prevTime; // start as undefined to prevent jumping

function tick(now) {
  // schedule next tick
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
  // calculate factor
  delta = (now - prevTime) / 1000;
  prevTime = now;
  if (isNaN(delta)) return; // skip very first delta to prevent jumping

  x += speed * delta;
  $square.css({
    left: x
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $square = $("#square");
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 30px;
}

#square {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
500 pixels in five seconds
<div id="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate the delta time (time in milliseconds between each frame). This can be done as @Chris G has done. If you want to easely get the delta time between frames and draw a moving object on **the canvas**, the easiest way would be to use a library such as [Canvas.js](https://gustavgenberg.github.io/handy-front-end/#canvasjs):

```js
const canvas = new Canvas('my-canvas', 500, 500);

canvas.on('start', function ( ctx, handyObject ) {

  handyObject.Ball = {
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    speed: 100 // Pixels per second
  };
  
});

canvas.on('update', function (handyObject, delta) {

  handyObject.Ball.x += handyObject.Ball.speed * delta; // The magic happens. The speed is multiplied with the delta which often is around 0.016. Delta time is the time since the ball was last updated. Using delta time will make sure the ball moves exactly the same no matter what framerate the client is running.
  
});

canvas.on('draw', function (ctx, handyObject, delta) {

  ctx.clear();

  ctx.beginPath();
  
  ctx.arc(handyObject.Ball.x, handyObject.Ball.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  
  ctx.fill();
  
});

canvas.start();
```

```html
<script src="https://gustavgenberg.github.io/handy-front-end/Canvas.js"></script>
```