# Does the animation run always with the same speed?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I have this portion of JavaScript code which draws a bar (for let's say a bar diagram):

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerHeight / 3 * 4;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
const xCharCnt = window.innerHeight / 3 * 4 / 48;
const yCharCnt = window.innerHeight / 34;

const foreground1 = "#AF5BEC";
let offset = 0;
const barHeight = 20;
const speed = 4;
const limit = yCharCnt * barHeight;

let requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(render);

function render() {
    requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
    
    // Clear screen
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Draw bar
    ctx.fillStyle = foreground1;
    ctx.fillRect(xCharCnt * 7, yCharCnt * 28, xCharCnt, -offset);
    offset = offset + speed;
    
    // Cancel animation
    if (offset >= limit) window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
}
```

Questions:

a) Is it the right way to do an animation?

b) Does the animation run always with the same speed, regardless the resolution of the device it's running on?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48113750/canvas-animation-duration-in-time

Answer (score 1):

It will be framerate dependent, so it will differ between devices.

> The number of callbacks is usually 60 times per second, but will generally match the display refresh rate in most web browsers as per W3C recommendation. requestAnimationFrame() calls are paused in most browsers when running in background tabs or hidden s in order to improve performance and battery life.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

The above link also gives a suggestion on how you should code your animations so they do always run at the same speed. Translated to your code that would look like:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerHeight / 3 * 4;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
const xCharCnt = window.innerHeight / 3 * 4 / 48;
const yCharCnt = window.innerHeight / 34;

const foreground1 = "#AF5BEC";
let offset = 0;
const barHeight = 20;
const speed = 4;
const limit = yCharCnt * barHeight;

let requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
let previousTimestamp;

function render(timestamp) {
    if(previousTimestamp === undefined) {
        previousTimestmap = timestamp;
    }

    const delta = timestamp - previousTimestamp;
    offset = Math.min(offset + (speed * delta), limit);

    // Clear screen
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Draw bar
    ctx.fillStyle = foreground1;
    ctx.fillRect(xCharCnt * 7, yCharCnt * 28, xCharCnt, -offset);
    
    // Cancel animation
    requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
    if (offset >= limit) window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);

    previousTimestmap = timestamp;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly the code as you modified my own doesn't work. Have you tested it? That's even my problem. Whenever I tried some code from the Internet and tried to modify it so it fits my needs it doesn't work any more. Your modification is the opposit and doesn't work neither.

Comment: I'm getting a blank page/screen. There is no error/exception in the console.